# Bayeux code example for Resin 4

Tags: jetty, comet, resin, cometd, bayeux

Anyone have working (simple) example source code of the Bayeux + Comet support in Resin 4?
Thanks.
(or if not, any for Jetty?)

Answer (score 0):

I do have something for Jetty, a sample app I called Jaye. Here's the url to it:
http://jaye.felipera.cloudbees.net

It uses Raphael JS for the map, Maven, Comet, Bayeux, Java, the usual suspects. You can checkout my blog post about it: http://geeks.aretotally.in/thinking-in-reverse-not-taking-orders-from-yo.

Inside the blog you will find the information for the source code and everything.

Let me know if I can help you with anything.

Thank you,
Felipe